# How do I connect/relate my model to my view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, model

I'm porting an application over to backbone and I'm not sure how to tie my model to my view?

I guess the first question, is, is it on an instance by instance basis, or is it something I can set once, so that every model instance ( of a certain type ) is connected to every view instance ( of a certain type ).

Here is my first guess / try:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
*/

    var ModelMediaPane = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            visible:          false,
            previous:         null,
            current:          'about'
        }
    });
    var model_media_pane = new ModelMediaPane();
    $A.log(model_media_pane.get('visible'));

    var ViewMediaPane = Backbone.View.extend({
        id: "mi_holder",
        events: {
        }
    });

    var view_media_pane = new ViewMediaPane({model:ModelMediaPane});
    $A.log(view_media_pane.el);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of ways to do that.

The simplest one is when you instantiate a view, you inject the model on your view passing the model instance. As you already doing.
or 
You can just create a variable called 'model' inside your view, and instantiate a new
model.

Replying your question,

If you use the same instance of a model to instantiate 2 views(any kind). The model will be the same for your two views. It means that if viewA and viewB are listening for events of the same model, they both will react to the same event.

example:

```
var modelA = new ModelA();
var ViewA = new ViewA({model:modelA});
var ViewB = new ViewB({model:modelA});
```

If you change something in modelA, both views will be reacting.

It makes possible you have two views listening for two different instance of the same model, it makes no sense to me, but depends of you rules.